# Display the title of a section (or subsection) in a reference

Tags: labels, ref

I understood how to use \ label {} and \ ref} to get the number of a section or subsection.
I would like to know if it was possible to also obtain the title of a section or sub-section.
For example (see VI.1 Test) where Test the title of the subsection

Comment: Take a look at the `nameref` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hyperref or cleveref packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    \section{Test}\label{sec:test}
    \ref{sec:test}
    \nameref{sec:test}
    
    \autoref{sec:test}
    
    \cref{sec:test}
    
\end{document}
```

You can define a `\newcommand` to fit your need:

```
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{(see \autoref{#1}~\nameref{#1}, p.~\pageref{#1})}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
can I remove the frame that surrounds the reference in the final document,

Comment: Sure! Use `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}`. See `hyperref` documentation.